# How to log in and check, if user is staff, can access to url or use a views class?

Tags: python, django

At my question, my problem is
How to log in and check, if user is staff, can access to url or use a views class ?

I want to user login on website (Not admin-console) and user is staff (in admin-console) can post.

And someone just have a account create on web (they dont have permission staff) thay just can login.

Thank you so much !

```
class PostCreateView(LoginRequiredMixin, CreateView):
    model = Post
    fields = ['title','content']
    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.instance.author = self.request.user
        return super().form_valid(form)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want only the staff user can access the view  then you can use the [UserPassesTestMixin](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/auth/default/#django.contrib.auth.mixins.UserPassesTestMixin) and [LoginRequiredMixin](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/auth/default/#django.contrib.auth.mixins.LoginRequiredMixin) like this:

```
class StaffRequiredMixin(LoginRequiredMixin, UserPassesTestMixin):

    def test_func(self):
        return self.request.user.is_staff
```

Now in your PostCreateView you can implement like this:

```
class PostCreateView(StaffRequiredMixin, CreateView):
     ......
```

Comment: haha yes, that's what i looking for. thank you so much. Love you <3 
I try use:
urlpatterns = patterns('', url(r'^applist/', staff_member_required(ApplicationListView.as_view())),

But it always direct me to admin console. you are my hero. Thank you so much again

Answer (score 2):

You can use `user.is_staff` to check this.

Ref: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/auth/#django.contrib.auth.models.User.is_staff

Answer (score 1):

Create a file named: ***permissions.py***

And then you can do something like below:

```
from rest_framework.permissions import BasePermission


class PermissionMixin:
    '''
        Initializes user permissions
    '''
    def __init__(self):
        self._actions = ()
        self._user = False
        self._admin = False

    def _initialize_permissions(self, request):
        self._actions = settings.ALLOWED_ACTIONS
        self._user = request.user and request.user.is_active
        self._admin = self._user and request.user.is_superuser


class AdminsOnlyPermission(BasePermission, PermissionMixin):
    '''
        Determines operations that can be performed by admins only
    '''
    def has_permission(self, request, view):
        self._initialize_permissions(request)

        if view.action in self._actions:
            return self._admin
        else:
            return False
```

Comment: thank you for answer, that's good ideal, i will try.
but i had something like: 
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^applist/', staff_member_required(ApplicationListView.as_view())),
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
)
I just add staff_member_required() to my urlpatterns. 
But anyway, tks so much ^^

Answer (score 1):

If you are using [DRF](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/), you can use IsAdminUser:

```
from rest_framework import mixins, viewsets
from rest_framework.permissions import IsAdminUser

from my_serializers import SomeSerializer


class SomeView(mixins.ListModelMixin, viewsets.GenericViewSet):
    serializer_class = SomeSerializer
    queryset = SomeSerializer.Meta.model.objects.all()
    permission_classes = [IsAdminUser]
```

It checks that there is a user logged in and that is has is_staff in true.